# Trouble connecting python to cx_oracle - error ORA-01804

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

im trying to connect my python to an oracle sql database but i keep getting a error ORA-01804, which appears to be a timezone error. Can someone please help figure this out?

I'm on Mac -- tried troubleshooting earlier answers but nothing has worked. I also dont know much about working with macs (i just got this laptop) so if you could, please be clear. thanks!

Comment: Unset ORACLE_HOME?  It would help if you told us what you had installed and how it was installed.  Follow the installation instructions closely: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html

Comment: @ChristopherJones thank you for the response i tried the installation instructions and using unset oracle_home-- however, im still getting this error.

Comment: @ChristopherJones i manually created an opt folder (bc i dont have access in work) in my finder (im on mac os catalina), created a lib folder in my users directory, and used ln -s to link the opt folder. anything im doing wrong?